# Uploaded Images need server reload

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

I am new at django.
I upload images and it was working well when in development.

I use pythonanywhere for deploy my code.

The problem is  I can upload image on admin but can't display unless reload the server.

I can show some code snippets you want.

I have no idea what the problem is

Also used Whitenoise to server media files. I added below the code I put to wsgi file in pythonanywhere

```
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)

application = WhiteNoise(
   DjangoWhiteNoise(get_wsgi_application()),
   root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
   prefix='/media/', 
)
```

Comment: I would suggest removing whitenoise, and replacing it with PythonAnywhere's official static files system, and using that same system to set up a MEDIA_URL and directory -- more info here: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles

Comment: I have used the official media files system for Media files and it worked. Still using whitenoise for static files. Thanks. I have solved the problem after two days.